# R httr curl 404 error

Tags: r, curl, http-headers, libcurl, httr

If I use the following in my terminal, It gets a response

```
curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/converse?v=20170120&session_id=aqblurqqfb&q=Hi' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer U4FSEI23I742US2MONJML3UHL3DYC4XO'
```

But I am writing an equivalent in R code using httr package's GET() function as

```
require(httr)
GET(url="https://api.wit.ai/converse?v=20170120&session_id=aqblurqqfb&q=Hi",
    add_headers("Content-Type"="application/json",Accept="application/json",
                 Authorization="Bearer U4FSEI23I742US2MONJML3UHL3DYC4XO"
               )
   )
```

But the above gets a 404 response when I run it in R. Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Well, it seems like you should be using `POST` and not `GET`.